# The “Navigtionmenu” control is not showing up in the Toolbox in a .NET project VS2010 and 2012

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, toolbox

Why The “Navigtionmenu” control is not showing up in the Toolbox in a .NET project VS2010 and 2012?

but why did the screenshot I got from google below appear toolbox "NavigtionMenu"?

Thanks
jack

[image: NavigtionMenu]

Comment: I could be wrong but feel the Navigation menu is _relatively new_ in comparison to VS2010 & VS2012 at least.  Any reason not to just use VS2022.  The community edition is free

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just did a search [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/) for "navigationmenu" and got no relevant matches, so I don't think that such a control even exists. Given the generic icon in that screenshot, it's probably a third-party control or even second-party, i.e. created by the person who posted that screenshot. In fact, I think that that is the icon that used to denote a user control and is still used for a user control in the *Add New Item* dialogue. I suggest that you check that link you found and see whether it includes instructions for creating it.